# Java Interfaces , Declaring an Interface

Tags: java

Why eclipse throws an error message while giving public modifier to interface

```
publid interface one // throws an error
{
}
```

Public type one must be defined in its own file error i am getting

please give your clarifications regarding this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file called 'one.java'. Place the declaration of your interface in there.

Every public class, interface etc. needs to be in its own file.

Answer (score 0):

Because your Java file containing `one` most probably is not named "one.java".

Answer (score 0):

Any public class or interface must be declared in a separate file, having the name of that interface or class.

If you have multiple top level classes/interfaces in the same file, only one of them can be public.